# Ranking position

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sum, ranking

I have a Rails application with the following models:

- User
- Bet

User has many_bets and Bets belongs_to User. Every Bet has a Profitloss value, which states how much the User has won/lost on that Bet.

So to calculate how much a specific User has won overall I cycle through his bets in the following way:

```
 User.bets.sum(:profitloss)
```

I would like to show the User his ranking compared to all the other Users, which could look something like this:

*"Your overall ranking: 37th place"*

To do so I need to sum up the overall winnings per User, and find out in which position the current user is.

How do I do that and how to do it, so it don't overload the server :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something similar to

```
User.join(:bets).
    select("users.id, sum(bets.profitloss) as accumulated").
    group("users.id").
    order("accumulated DESC")
```

and then search in the resulting list of "users" (not real users, they have only two meaningful attributes, their ID and a `accumulated` attribute with the sum), for the one corresponding to the current one.

In any case to get a single user's position, you have to calculate all users' `accumulated`, but at least this is only one query. Even better, you can store in the user model the accumulated value, and query just it for ranking.

Comment: I guess I get an array with the users sorted after who has the highest profitloss. How do I then find a specific User in this array and see which position he has. Like ex 37th place.

Comment: sorry about the late respone to your answers - my wife just gave birth the other day, so I've been busy :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large number of Users and Bets, you won't be able to compute and sort the global profitloss of each user "on demand", so I suggest that you use a [rake task](http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks) that you schedule regularly (once a day, every hour, etc...)

Add a column `position` in the `User` model, get the list of all Users, compute their global profitloss, sort the list of Users with their profitloss, and finally update the `position` attribute of each `User` with their position in the list.

Comment: I surely see your point and I'm considering using a rake task to calculate these rankings and then just recalculate them every hour or so. They are not critical to the application and can easyly be an hour old.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do it is to keep a pre calculated total in your database either on `user` model itself or on a separate model that has 1:1 relation to `user`. If you don't do this, you will have to calculate sum for all users at all times in order to get their rating, which means full table operation on `bets` table. This said, this query will give you desired results, if more than 1 person has the same total, it will count both as rating X:

```
select id, (select count(h.id) from users u inner join 
(select user_id, sum(profitloss) as `total` from bets group by user_id) b2
on b2.user_id = u.id, (select id from users) h inner join
(select user_id, sum(profitloss) as `total` from bets group by user_id) b 
on b.user_id = h.id where u.id = 1 and (b.total > b2.total)) 
as `rating` from users where id = 1;
```

You will need to plug `user.id` into query in `where id = X`

if you add a column to `user` table to keep track of their total, query is a little simpler, in this example column name is `total_profit_loss`:

```
select id, total_profit_loss, (select count(h.username)+1 from users u, 
(select username, score from users) h 
where id = 1 and (h.total_profit_loss > u.total_profit_loss)) 
as `rating` from users where id = 1;
```

Comment: If the `User` model has a column `total_profit_loss`, the position of the user `u` is simply `User.where('total_profit_loss > ?', u.total_profit_loss).count + 1`

Comment: I see where you are going with this, but the SQL is a bit too complex for me (I'm lacking some sql skills)..